# Separate compilation of OCaml modules

Tags: ocaml

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771674/compiling-multiple-ocaml-files)  and others, 
but my compile problem is unsolved.

I am testing separate compilation with these files:

testmoda.ml

```
module Testmoda = struct
  let greeter () = print_endline "greetings from module a"
end
```

testmodb.ml

```
module Testmodb = struct
  let dogreet () = print_endline "Modul B:"; Testmoda.greeter ()
end
```

testmod.ml

```
let main () =
  print_endline "Calling modules now...";
  Testmoda.greeter ();
  Testmodb.dogreet (); 
  print_endline "End."
;;
let _ = main ()
```

Now I generate the .mli file

```
ocamlc -c -i testmoda.ml >testmoda.mli
```

and the testmoda.cmi is there.

Next I create the .cmo file without errors:

```
ocamlc -c testmoda.ml
```

Fine, so do the same with testmodb.ml:

```
strobel@s131-amd:~/Ocaml/ml/testmod> ocamlc -c -i testmodb.ml >testmodb.mli
File "testmodb.ml", line 3, characters 45-61:
Error: Unbound value Testmoda.greeter
```

Another try:

```
strobel@s131-amd:~/Ocaml/ml/testmod> ocamlc -c testmoda.cmo testmodb.ml
File "testmodb.ml", line 3, characters 45-61:
Error: Unbound value Testmoda.greeter
```

Other combinations failed as well.

How do I compile testmodb.ml and testmod.ml? This should be easy - without ocamlbuild / omake /
oasis, I think.

Syntax errors in the files are excluded,
if I cat them together to one file (with the required space between) it compiles
and executes perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OCaml gives you a module for free at the top level of each source file. So your first module is actually named `Testmoda.Testmoda`, the function is named `Testmoda.Testmoda.greeter`, and so on. Things will work better if your files just contain the function definitions.

As a side comment, if you're going to use the interface generated by `ocamlc -i`, you really don't need mli files. The interface in the absence of an mli file is the same as the one generated by `ocamlc -i`. If you don't want the default interface, using `ocamlc -i` gives a good starting point for your mli file. But for a simple example like this, it just makes things look a lot more complicated than they really are (IMHO).

If you modify your files as I describe (remove extra module declarations), you can compile and run from scratch as follows:

```
$ ls
testmod.ml  testmoda.ml testmodb.ml
$ cat testmoda.ml
let greeter () = print_endline "greetings from module a"
$ cat testmodb.ml
let dogreet () = print_endline "Modul B:"; Testmoda.greeter ()
$ ocamlc -o testmod testmoda.ml testmodb.ml testmod.ml
$ ./testmod
Calling modules now...
greetings from module a
Modul B:
greetings from module a
End.
```

If you have already compiled a file (with `ocamlc -c file.ml`) you can replace `.ml` with `.cmo` in the above command. This works even if all the filenames are `.cmo` files; in that case ocamlc just links them together for you.

Comment: oh miracle, without the explicit module definition it works as expected, an `ocamlc -c testmoda.ml` creates the .cmi and .cmo , the latter can be used for compiling testmod.ml - separate compilation.

Comment: (could not edit comment) So here the separate compilation: `ocamlc -c testmoda.ml;ocamlc -c testmodb.ml; ocamlc -o testmod testmoda.cmo testmodb.cmo testmod.ml`

Comment: Note that the single command I gave also does separate compilation :-) It's completely equivalent to these three commands. But of course sometimes you want to compile just one of the source files as you show. It also works for `testmod.ml`.