# How do I compile and run OCaml programs

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have two separate OCaml files as follows

`a.ml`

```
let hello str = "hello from" ^ str
```

and `b.ml`

```
A.hello "Module B"
```

to compile and run,  I did the following one after the other

```
ocamlc -c a.ml
ocamlc -c b.ml
ocamlc -o a.cmo b.cmo
```

the first two command runs without an error.But when I execute the last command I get the following error

```
> File "_none_", line 1: Error: Error while linking b.cmo: Reference to
> undefined global `A'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: See [accepted answer to this question][1], there is a complete example.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028151/separate-compilation-of-ocaml-modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling and running in Ocaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028789/compiling-and-running-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 3):

`ocamlc -o myprogram.byte a.cmo b.cmo` maybe ? `man ocamlc` may be useful.

Comment: how do i run the resulting byte file?

Comment: It's an executable, just as normal. If you didn't notice, `a.cmo` is being set as the out file, not as an additional file to link against.

Comment: I do not get an output in my terminal when i run ./myprogram.byte

Comment: Why would you? You aren't printing anything.

Comment: yeah okay. I noticed something unusual though. when i run "ocamlc -o myprogram a.cmo b.cmo" it works.The error appears only when i don't specify the output file name.the man page says the default will be named a.out though

Comment: If you specify `-o a.cmo` it's going to write to the file `a.cmo`, again `man ocamlc`, `-o` has a mandatory argument. If you want the default exec name don't specify `-o`.