# Compiling and running in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to OCaml and I would like to know how can I write an ocaml code into a file and then compile it to run it whenever I want.
Now I'm using OCaml by typing `ocaml` in the mac or linux terminal and writing the code, but when I'm done and I close the software I lose all the work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There're plenty of options, but the easiest one (to my opinion) is to use [`ocamlbuild`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/ocamlbuild.html). If you have your code in file `program.ml`, then

```
ocamlbuild program.native
```

will compile your program into a native binary, so that you can run it as simple as:

```
./program.native
```

There is also a shortcut that allows you to compile and run a program as one action:

```
ocamlbuild program.native --
```

You can pass arguments to your program after the `--` sign.

If your program consists of more than one file, that's not a problem, as `ocamlbuild` will scan it, and automatically build all dependencies in a correct order.

If your program requires external libraries, then you can specify them with a `-pkg` or `-pkgs` option. Like this:

```
ocamlbuild -pkg lwt program.native
```

Comment: You can also use the `ocamlc` bytecode compiler and `ocamlopt` native compiler, e.g. in your `Makefile`

Comment: What are the differences between `ocamlbuild` and `ocamlc`?

Comment: `ocamlc` and `ocamlopt` are compilers. `ocamlbuild` is an automation tool, that uses them behind the scene. You can use `ocamlbuild`'s `-classic-output` option to look what is actually happening.

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking this tutorial - [Compiling OCaml projects](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/compiling_ocaml_projects.html) might help. It describes the basics of compiling OCaml. It discusses `ocamlc` and `ocamlopt` compilers in depth and other compiler tools.

Comment: It does help. Thanks.

Comment: I read all the `ocaml.org` tutorials when learning OCaml. Helped Alot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jane Street's Core, you should consider using the command `corebuild` to compile, which includes a bunch of defaults after `ocamlbuild`:

`ocamlbuild \
    -use-ocamlfind \
    -pkg core \
    -tag "ppx(ppx-jane -as-ppx)" \
    -tag thread \
    -tag debug \
    -tag bin_annot \
    -tag short_paths \
    -cflags "-w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44" \
    -cflags -strict-sequence \
    "$@"`

I got this [here](https://github.com/janestreet/core/blob/master/corebuild).